# Avoid sending emails to manager while deleting My Site in Moss

Tags: 2007, my-site, email

I want to stop the functionality of sending email to the manager of user whose mysite is going to be deleted rather mysite cleanup activity if below things happened to user/user profile:

1) If he left the domain
2) the user has been completely removed from AD

Solution found from internet:

1. To check Site Use Confirmation and Deletion
2. To disable My Site CleanUp Job from Central Administration

Analysis done upon the above found solutions:

1) In Site Use Confirmation and Deletion page, two options available

a) send an email notification to owners of unused site colletions -- it is unchecked in our environment

b) Automatically delete the site collection if use is not confirmed -- It is disabled

2) The My Site CleanUp Job from Central Administration is enabled

Queries:

1) How to enable the option(b) in Site Use Confirmation and Deletion page?

2) If My Site CleanUp Job is disabled then will it stop sending email to manager of the user?

Please suggest the solution if any either through Central Administration/SSP configuration settings or programmatically to this.

Answer (score 2):

To turn off automatic deletion of MySites, you must disable the Job Definition. Navigate to Central Admin > Monitoring > Review Job Definitions > Keep the view set to All and look through the list until you find "My Site Cleanup Job". Disable it and that should prevent the automatic deletion.

I'm unsure if this disables the nofications also.

Answer (score 1):

The Site Use Confirmation and Deletion settings are configured for a given web application so if My Sites is on its own web application then there would be no impact to any other site collections.

Go to Central Administration, Application Management, Site Use Confirmation and Deletion and uncheck the first checkbox ("Send e-mail notifications to owners of unused site collections").  When that is unchecked, it also disabled the auto-deletion option.

Comment: I think this is a different type of notification.  We currently have our site use confirmation and deletion completely disabled but we still have managers that get e-mailed about mysites when an employee that works for them gets disabled or deleted (I can't remember which) in AD.

Comment: I missed that part.  I'm not sure how you can disable that, its built into the system.  I think you would have to remove the reporting structure so that it cannot determine the manager.

Answer (score 0):

The email being sent to the manager is a "fib" if the auto site deletion is not enabled, the site will not be deleted.  The manager will still get the email because of the mysite cleanup timer job.

Answer (score 0):

It don't have a proper solution for it, but maybe a (dirty) workaround:

Can't you just edit the "manager" field in AD before you delete the account and fill in your account or some kind of service account? So the mail will still be sent out but won't disturb the manager since it will be sent to another email adress?!